# Can you use pyttsx3 to say something in discord voice channel

Tags: python, discord, text-to-speech, pyttsx

I want to create a bot that reads the messages of a specific text channel and speaks it you loud in a voice channel I use pyttsx3 to say it out loud locally on my laptop.

```
import discord
import pyttsx3

class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        messageContent = message.content
        print(messageContent)
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        engine.say(messageContent)
        engine.runAndWait()

client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

please help me

Comment: Please consider to re-generate your bot token as it was public and can be seen in the edit queue.

Comment: Without actually knowing anything about the APIs involved, I'd say that you need to find a way to get the `pyttsx3` engine to either out to a file on disc or to a structure in memory that the discord module can consume. I'd look at related questions regarding having bots play arbitrary audio in voice channels,